# Timestamp-based join on two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let we have two relations, `foos` and `bars` with the following DDLs:

```
CREATE TABLE foos(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY, -- surrogate key
    name character varying (255) NOT NULL,
    inserted_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE bars(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY, -- surrogate key
    passkey character (5) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    inserted_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);
```

As you may see, there is no foreign key in either of those tables.
However, I want to join them with their timestamps. The problem is, the timestamps we are gonna join does not overlap.

Let me explain the issue with a canonical example.

Assume we have those tuples in the tables:

```
INSERT INTO foos (name, inserted_at) VALUES 
    ('brian', '2017-01-16 04:52:41.060506'),
    ('alice', '2017-01-16 08:22:15.012303'),
    ('shan', '2017-01-16 10:36:45.123872'),
    ('marshall', '2017-01-16 10:41:49.123822'),
    ('jane', '2017-01-16 14:22:39.123123');

INSERT INTO bars (passkey, inserted_at) VALUES
    ('812he', '2017-01-16 04:53:18.123123'),
    ('1237s', '2017-01-16 08:23:02.120332'),
    ('asd72', '2017-01-16 10:42:52.123746'),
    ('asdks', '2017-01-16 14:23:11.123123');
```

The SQL query I would like to execute should fetch the rows like so:

```
query(name, passkey)::

    ('brian', '812he')
    ('alice', '1237s')
    ('marshall', 'asd72')
    ('jane', 'asdks')
```

Notice table `bars` joined with table `foos` by comparing their `inserted_at` values. Each `bar` is getting paired with closest `foo`.

How to write that kind of SQL query? Is it even a join operation?

If it concerns, I'm using *PostgreSQL 9.6.1*.

---

**A little explanation of why I decided to constitute a schema like that:**

The tables I gave are just canonical examples. In reality, the `foos` table is a union of five tables, who are concrete tables of sibling subclasses. The foreign key approach would lead me to put five foreign keys to the `bars` table, in order to preserve integrity. However, only one those keys would be there, so this did not make sense at the end (and I could not managed to apply an external predicate which checks that).

**Do timestamps have a relation between each other?**

Yes, each `foo` could be matched if and only if it has a corresponding `bar` in three minutes of future.

Comment: don't use varchar(255) in Pg. There is no point. just use text.

Comment: Also, do we have insurance that every foo matches to one bar? This is a bad schema, you should have created a fkey in bars that links to foo.

Comment: I disagree on your reasoning because you're not ensuring integrity, but you want `shan` to drop off in your example based on the interval distance between `shan` and the neighboring passkeys?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Exactly. Could you suggest me a better scheme?

Comment: I don't have all of your data, I'd need to know what *five tables who are concrete tables of sibling subclasses* means in this context. Chances are you not want *five tables who are concrete tables of sibling subclasses*. You want one table, with a foreign key, and perhaps five views of it.

Comment: I would accept @Tim's answer here, and ask for a review on dba.stackexchange.com, tag it postgres, postgres-9.6, and database-design.

Comment: What if we have `('shan', '2017-01-16 10:39:45.123872')` instead, should it be joined with `('asd72', '2017-01-16 10:42:52.123746')`, too? I is the closest foo and less than 3 minutes in the future.

Comment: @miracle173 No it should not be joined with anything since it has a successor, `('marshall', '2017-01-16 10:41:49.123822')`.

Comment: @Leviathlon And does the selected answer comply with this requirement? I can't test it but I don't think it will work. Chnage to `('shan', '2017-01-16 10:40:59.123872')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the rule of thumb that two record which were inserted within 2 minutes of each other should be joined, then we can write the following query:

```
SELECT f.name, b.passkey
FROM foos f
INNER JOIN bars b
    ON GREATEST(b.inserted_at, f.inserted_at) -
       LEAST(b.inserted_at, f.inserted_at) < interval '2 minutes'  -- or another interval
```

**Explanation:**

We need to use a workaround of some kind to compute the absolute difference between two timestamps.  The reason is that we don't know in advance whether a timestamp from `foos` or one from `bars` will be greater than the other.  The `GREATEST/LEAST` trick is one option.  After doing this, this difference is then compared against the interval 2 minutes.

Comment: I should say this is really impressive, if it works.

Comment: @Leviathlon Emphasis on the `if it works` part ... you know what, I have Postgres running here, let me try it.

Comment: No offense, by the way. It looks like its working, my tests pass actually. I'm just impressed how things could be done like that.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Then you should be commenting on the OP, not my answer.  If we must join on close timestamps, we need an interval.  And I keep kosher, by the way, LOL.

Comment: I knew there was something fishy here. You were right from his simplification of the problem's domain, but there was more to it. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161405/designing-an-extensible-authentication-system/161408#comment310389_161405